# Pythonanywhere: pytube

Tags: python, flask, storage, pytube, download

Tengo una API en flask desplegada en Pythonanywhere (en su versión free para probar), mi problema es que no me deja descargar videos de Youtube usando pytube. Esta forma que es la que encontre en la documentación de pytube (`yt.streams.first().download(path)`), eso lo tengo dentro de un try y siempre me salta al except. Al correr mi app en el localhost si funciona, qué puedo hacer?

Adjunto mi código

```py
import errno
import os
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pytube import YouTube
app = Flask(__name__)

def complete_func(stream, path):
    with open('flask_api/logs', 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'stream: {stream}\n')
        f.write(f'path: {path}')

def write_file(url, path):
    yt = YouTube(url, on_complete_callback=complete_func)

    try:
        yt.streams.first().download(path)
        return jsonify({"msg": "download complete"}), 200
    except:
        return jsonify({"msg": "download error"}), 400


def check_video_url(video_id):
    checker_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
    video_url = checker_url + video_id
    request = requests.get(video_url)
    # print(request)
    return request.status_code == 200


@app.route("/youtube", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def getFromYoutube():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "recived GET"
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        body = request.get_json()
        if body is None:
            return jsonify({"msg": "The request body is null"}), 400
        elif 'video_id' not in body:
            return jsonify({"msg": "video_id is null"}), 400
        else:
            if not check_video_url(body["video_id"]):
                return jsonify({"msg": "invalid video_id"}), 400
            else:
                try:
                    os.mkdir('flask_api/downloads')
                except OSError as e:
                    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                        raise

                path = 'flask_api/downloads'
                url = f'https://www.youtube.com/embed/{body["video_id"]}'
                return write_file(url, path)


# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127487/discussion-on-question-by-eduar2-pythonanywhere-pytube).